# Xcode 7.2 after using 7.3 - no simulators listed

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, xcode7.2

I was working in Xcode 7.3 last night but it was crashing for some crazy reason whenever I tried to debug, but this isn't the issue.

Point is, I'm trying to downgrade to Xcode 7.2 (not 7.2.1, from https://developer.apple.com/downloads/). I've downloaded and installed from the dmg and have Xcode 7.2 running, however none of my simulators are listed for currently existing projects that I had worked with in 7.3. How do I get them to appear?

[image: Prompt to use 'Generic iOS Device']

[image: No iOS simulators listed]

When I create a new project, the iOS simulators show up correctly. See below:

[image: Correctly listed simulators in new project]

Answer (score 2):

Just go to Window > Devices and click the "+" Button in the lower left corner. There you should be able to add any simulator you need.

If that doesn't work, you can check Xcode > Preferences > Downloads and try to download simulators.

Comment: Just go to Window > Devices and click the "+" Button in the lower left corner

Works for me.
Thank you...!!